# how to get activity in service using startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to start a service which opens GPS dialogue if it is off on device boot process. I have a broadcast receiver on boot then I trigger this service to open dialogue without opening the main application.I am using service, in service I need to call GPS location dialogue box to turn on if disable.

```
public class GPSTestService extends Service  implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener ,VolleyResultCallBack {
private boolean ContinueConnection = true;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;
Context contex;
@Override
public void onVolleyErrorListener(VolleyError error) {

}

@Override
public void onVolleyResultListener(Context mContext, JSONArray response) {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    contex=getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    //...
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPSTestService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().

                        status.startResolutionForResult((Activity) contex,  REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    //...
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   // Utils.getInstance().syncData(this,this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

}

I have an issue with *status.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context,  REQUEST_LOCATION);* how to deal it in service? as we can not pass activity here.

Comment: You should check if location is enabled or not from View (i.e Activity or Fragment) and then start the service if all is well.

Comment: @SandipSoni basically I have to show GPS dialogue box when the device boots(when device turn on). so how I can start a fragment/Activity without opening the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in service I need to call GPS location dialogue box to turn on if disable

That is not possible, sorry. Do that work in your activity before starting the service. If the service detects that the user disabled location access while the service is running, the service can raise a `Notification` which leads the user to an activity where you can request GPS access.

Comment: is it impossible to open GPS location Dialogue box when the device turns on (if GPS is disabled)? if I work in activity then how I can I execute my activity when device turn on?

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan: "is it impossible to open GPS location Dialogue box when the device turns on (if GPS is disabled)?" -- you should display a `Notification` and allow the user to deal with the issue when the user is ready to do so.

Comment: that is also an awesome way to deal with.Thank you